# How to access hashi corp vault secret in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, hashicorp-vault

Hi I have added secret in my hashi corp vault in the below path

cep-kv/dev/sqlpassword

I am trying to access secret in my manifest as below

```
spec:
      serviceAccountName: default
      containers: # List
        - name: cep-container
          image: myinage:latest
          env:
          - name: AppSettings__Key
            value: vault:cep-kv/dev/sqlpassword#sqlpassword
```

This is throwing error below

```
failed to inject secrets from vault: failed to read secret from path: cep-kv/dev/sqlpassword: Error making API request.\n\nURL: GET https://vaultnet/v1/cep-kv/dev/sqlpassword?version=-1\nCode: 403. Errors:\n\n* 1 error occurred:\n\t* permission denied\n\n" app=vault-env
```

Is the path I am trying to access is correct value:

> vault:cep-kv/dev/sqlpassword#sqlpassword

I tried with below path too

```
value: vault:cep-kv/dev/sqlpassword
```

This says secret not found in respective path. Can someone help me to get secret from hashi corp vault. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are getting 403 permission you need to Configure Kubernetes authentication, you can configure authentication from the following step:

1. Enable the Kubernetes auth method:

> `vault enable auth kubernetes`

2. Configure the Kubernetes authentication method to use the location of the Kubernetes API

```
vault write auth/kubernetes/config \
  kubernetes_host=https://192.168.99.100:<your TCP port or blank for 443>
```

3. Create a named role:

   ```
   vault write auth/kubernetes/role/demo \
                bound_service_account_names=myapp \
                    bound_service_account_namespaces=default \
                    policies=default \
                ttl=1h
   ```
4. Write out the ” myapp ” policy that enables the “read” capability for secrets at the path .

   ```
   vault policy write myapp -path "yourpath"                                                  
   {  capabilities = ["read"] }
   ```

For more information follow [Configuration](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/docs/auth/kubernetes#configuration), Here is a [blog](https://blog.cloudthat.com/detailed-guide-to-securely-manage-secrets-for-kubernetes-using-hashicorp-vault/) explaining the usage of secrets in kubernetes.

Comment: Why not use Vault Operator to sync to native Kubernetes Secret?